# Order of Class Definitions in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference, definition

I've got a bit of a problem here.  I'm trying to define several classes, of which some are Players and some are Pawns belonging to the players.  Coming from Python, I'm used to being able to conveniently access a Pawn's owning Player through the Pawn, as well as accessing a Player's Pawns through the Player.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems impossible in C++.

I currently define Player first, and one of its data members `m_Pawns` is supposed to be a `vector<Pawn>`.  I declare the data member, but I don't assign it any value.  I also define a member function that is meant to assign a vector of pawns to `m_Pawns`, but I don't call it anywhere near the constructor.  Since I'm not actually calling the constructor for `Pawn` in the constructor for `Player`, it seems I should be fine.

Here's my `Player` class.  The `Board` class is defined beforehand, whereas the `Pawn` class is defined afterwards (the `Pawn` class contains pointers to an owner of the `Player` class, so switching it around doesn't really help).

```
class Player
{
public:
    Player(sf::Color color, const string& name);
    sf::Color GetColor();
    string GetName();
    void CreatePawns(Board& board, int which);
protected:
    vector<Pawn> m_Pawns;
    sf::Color m_Color;
    string m_Name;
};

Player::Player(sf::Color color, const string& name):
    m_Color(color),
    m_Name(name)
{}

sf::Color Player::GetColor()
{
    return m_Color;
}

string Player::GetName()
{
    return m_Name;
}

void Player::CreatePawns(Board& board, int which)
{
    switch(which)
    {
    case 1:
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            m_Pawns.push_back(Pawn((*board).Cluster1[i], this*, m_Color));
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            m_Pawns.push_back(Pawn((*board).Cluster2[i], this*, m_Color));
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            m_Pawns.push_back(Pawn((*board).Cluster3[i], this*, m_Color));
        }
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid player ID!\n\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: use forward declaration ... see this link http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `class Player` is coming first and `class Pawn` coming later then you can **only declare pointer or reference to the later class** (here `Pawn`). You **cannot have objects of later class**, e.g.

```
class Player {
  Pawn* p; // allowed
  Pawn& r; // allowed
  vector<Pawn*> p; // allowed
  vector<Pawn&> vr; // not allowed (reference are not copyable)
  vector<Pawn> o; // error !
};

class Pawn {};
```

There is no way you can overcome this situation, as in C++ for `non-template` class one need to show full definition to declare objects.

The only way out is to reformat your code or use pointer/reference (with **forward declaration**).

Comment: Your example does neither show pointers, nor references, nor a value. It declares a vector-to-... thereof. You can very well use forward declared typenames as template arguments. E.g. one way to implement pimpl-types: `class FooImpl; class Foo { boost::shared_ptr<FooImpl> impl_; }`

Comment: Also: A vector of references isn't possible. References are not copyable types.

Comment: I tried flipping things around so that Pawns are defined first, and require only a pointer to a Player (as an initial data member as well as in the constructor), but I still get the same error message.  Do I have to use forward declaration no matter what, even with pointers?

Comment: @GarricW, yes forward declaration is mandatory for using pointer or references in such case.

Comment: All right, so I think I've got everything working.  Just one minor error left that I can't seem to clear up.  What's wrong with this line?  board is a reference, this* is supposed to be a pointer to the Player instance using the function. `m_Pawns.push_back(Pawn(board.Cluster2[i], this*, m_Color));`.  I get a `expected primary-expression before ',' token` and the same error with '('.

Comment: I've also tried an alternative, with identical results: `Pawn newPawn(board.Cluster1[i], this*, m_Color);
            m_Pawns.push_back(newPawn);`

Comment: The answer is still wrong. `vector<Pawn>` works just fine with a forward-declared `Pawn`.

Answer (score 0):

The class Pawn still has to be defined so compiled can instantiate vector. You can get away with storing references or pointers to Pawn objects in your vector instead of values; vector for example. In that case forward declaration of class Pawn will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class Pawn;

class Player {
}

class Pawn {
}
```

Comment: Also forgot to mention what that should be done. This is called forward declaration. parashift.com has a comprehensive reference to C++.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* switch it around, because you can forward declare `Player`, and then `Pawn` *can* have a pointer to it.

You *can* take a pointer to an incomplete type. You *can't* hold values of that type.