# Public struct inside c++ class

Tags: c++, struct, inner-classes

I'm trying to define a public struct inside a C++ class, and can't figure out how to make it compile.  In my header, I have the following:

```
class AtomUtility
{
    public:
        struct BoundingBox;
        void doWork(struct AtomUtility::BoundingBox bounds);
};
```

And in the source:

```
#include"AtomUtility.h"
struct AtomUtility::BoundingBox
{
    double xMin, xMax;
};
int main()
{
    AtomUtility::BoundingBox *myBox = new AtomUtility::BoundingBox;
    myBox->xMin = 0;
    myBox->xMax = 10;
    AtomUtility *myUtility = new AtomUtility;
    myUtility->doWork(*myBox);
    delete myUtility;
}
void AtomUtility::doWork(struct AtomUtilty::BoundingBox bounds)
{
    //do things...
}
```

When I attempt to compile this, I get an error: "class "AtomUtility" has no tag member named "BoundingBox".

Comment: there is at least a ; missing at the end of the struct definition

Comment: You don't need to say `struct` in C++. It's not C.

Comment: @KerrekSB He does in all of the contexts he's using it in here.

Comment: @JamesKanze, not when declaring the parameter of `doWork`

Comment: 1. Is there a special reason you are using this sort of syntax instead of declaring the struct before and then just using it as a member? 2. @Kerrek SB, where I work we use `struct` in C++ to denote a class that all its members are public and has no methods, like a C struct.

Comment: When I define BoundingBox in a separate file, it compiles just fine!  Thanks for the suggestion, @Digital Da.  I had no good reason to define it here, other than the brevity of the BoundingBox definition.

Answer (score 2):

You've missed the semi-colon after the definition of `AtomUtility::BoundingBox` and your compiler is getting confused and giving a poor diagnostic.

You're also trying to pass a `AtomUtility::BoundingBox*` to a function expecting a `AtomUtility::BoundingBox`

If your compiler gives poor diagnostics it's often useful to try your code on a different compiler. Several are available online, e.g. [Comeau](http://comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/),  [Clang](http://llvm.org/demo/), or a pastebin that compiles, such as http://codepad.org

Comment: Sorry, these are two typos made copying from my terminal.

Comment: There's also a typo in the definition of `doWork: AtomUtilty`. With those fixed the code is OK, if your compiler rejects it then it's a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting https://stackoverflow.com/a/6368118/1483826:

> you can only declare pointer or reference to the later class (...). You cannot have objects of later class.

To fix this, you'd need to declare the struct before the class using it as a field.

Comment: By "field", do you mean data member? Because it isn't used as a data member.

Comment: So the compiler defines BoundingBox later, even though it's the first thing in the source file?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I'm not sure about the naming convention, I meant it or its reference/pointer would be part of the object.
[EDIT]: My bad, I see it now.

Comment: But it isn't used in the object. It's not used until after it's defined, which is OK.